# Which TChart property to use in Delphi 10.1 Berlin instead of TeeUseMouseWheel?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10.1-berlin

When I build my project in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, there is an error:

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TeeUseMouseWheel' Field

`TeeUseMouseWheel` works in Delphi 2006, so which property can I use instead in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution was posted on Steema's [forum](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12765):

> This variable has been moved to a new property at:
>
> ```
> Chart.Panning.MouseWheel
> ```
>
> This new MouseWheel property is TPanMouseWheel type:
>
> ```
> TPanMouseWheel=(pmwNormal, pmwInverted, pmwNone);
> ```
>
> So you can do (if your chart is named Chart1):
>
> ```
> Chart1.Panning.MouseWheel:=pmwNormal; //pmwInverted //pmwNone
> ```